# Hyper-v network driver not signed

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

I've recently moved a Virtual machine from a server to another one.
Both the servers are running Windows Server 2012 R2 as the guest host.

The generation 2 VM run almost perfectly, but it doesn't recognize the network adapter.

Integration services are updated (if I try to re-install it it says they are already updated and doesn't let me repair it).

On device manager I see the exclamation mark left to the adapter.
If I let it search for drivers in C:\Windows it says that the "Network adapter for Hyper-V" is found, but it isn't digitally signed, so it won't be installed.

Anyone could help me making this adapter work?
I couldn't figure out how to remove and re-install integration services either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.
I had to Disable Driver Signature Enforcement in the advanced boot options.